# Image scale from CSS

Tags: css, scale, angular2-template, image-scaling, image-size

How can I scale from CSS an image to which I set the width and height. Currently, it looks very stretched.
This is what I did in my HTML:

```
<div id="notification-media" *ngIf="notification.type < 200">                            
   <img src="{{notification.video.thumbnail}}" id="notification-video-image"/>
</div>
```

And in my CSS file:

```
#notification-video-image{
    width: 96px;
    height:54px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

 #notification-media{
     width: 30%;
     float: right;
     margin-right: 18px;
 }
```

I, also, tried to set `background-size:cover` and `width:100%; , height:100%;`, but it didn't drive me to the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set either `width` or `height` to `auto`.

```
#notification-video-image{
    width: 96px; // auto or
    height:54px; // auto
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```